# django urlpattern placement

Tags: django, django-urls

In my django app there is a separate application for auth purposes. My main urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^auth/', include('auth.urls', namespace='auth'), name='auth'),
    ...
]
```

My auth urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.log_in, name='auth'),
]
```

Now I want to put logout view into my auth application and bind it with '/logout'. As far as there is only one url ('/auth') which leads to my auth app where and how should I put '/logout' urlpattern?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your `logout` url to be `/logout` (with no `/auth/` prefix) you can remove `auth` from the include.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('auth.urls', namespace='auth'), name='auth'),

]
```

Note that this will affect your existing auth URL patterns, so I've changed the regex for `views.log_in` below:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^auth$', views.log_in, name='auth'),
    url(r'^logout$', views.logout),
]
```

Another other option is to leave `auth/urls.py` as it is, and add a pattern for `logout` to your main `urls.py`:

```
from auth.views import logout

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^auth/', include('auth.urls', namespace='auth'), name='auth'),
    url(r'^logout$', logout, name='logout')
]
```